# Creating automatized Presentation and Formatting POWERPOINT slides in 1920 x 1080 NO DUPLICATE

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, powerpoint, yfinance

I use yfinance to download financial data from yahoo finance. For this I have written a code that can be used to get the data. I then use the data to plot distribution charts with Searborn and then automatically import them into a PowerPoint file.

However, I don't like the formatting of the result.

- I would like both the graphic files and the PowerPoint slides to be displayed in full HD, 1920 x 1080.

How would I have to change my code?

Attached is my code and example of the graphics file.

Will be grateful for any assistance.

```
 #Code example stack overflow

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

tickers = ['SIE.DE', 'SIEGY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMD', 'CVX', 'RKT', 'IBKR', 'UWMC', 'BLDR', 'OWL', 'IOT', 'WSO','DECK', 'RIVN', 'MELI', 'DDOG', 'CRM']

# Define a function to get the data for a single ticker
def get_ticker_data(ticker):
    t = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    info = t.info
    isin = t.isin

    # Keep only the desired attributes
    selected_info = {}    
    for key in ['symbol', 'shortName', 'country', 'sector', 'industry', 'marketCap', 'enterpriseValue', 'ebitdaMargins', 
                'profitMargins','grossMargins', 'operatingMargins', 'revenueGrowth', 'earningsGrowth', 
                'earningsQuarterlyGrowth', 'grossProfits', 'ebitda', 'operatingCashflow', 'freeCashflow', 'totalCash', 
                'totalDebt', 'totalRevenue', 'netIncomeToCommon', 'totalCashPerShare', 'bookValue', 
                'enterpriseToEbitda', 'enterpriseToRevenue', 'priceToSalesTrailing12Months', 'trailingPE', 'forwardPE', 
                'priceToBook', 'revenuePerShare', 'trailingEps', 'forwardEps', 'dividendRate', 'lastDividendValue', 
                'dividendYield', 'trailingAnnualDividendRate', 'fiveYearAvgDividendYield', 'trailingAnnualDividendYield', 
                'payoutRatio', 'returnOnAssets', 'returnOnEquity',   
                'trailingPegRatio', 'pegRatio', 'debtToEquity', 'currentRatio', 'quickRatio', 'beta', 
                'sharesOutstanding', 'impliedSharesOutstanding', 'floatShares', 'sharesShort', 'sharesPercentSharesOut', 
                'shortRatio', 'sharesShortPreviousMonthDate', 'shortPercentOfFloat', 'sharesShortPriorMonth', 'currentPrice', 
                'fiftyDayAverage', 'twoHundredDayAverage', 'fiftyTwoWeekHigh', 
                'fiftyTwoWeekLow', '52WeekChange', 'currency', 'financialCurrency', 'recommendationKey', 'targetLowPrice', 
                'targetMedianPrice', 'targetMeanPrice', 'targetHighPrice', 'recommendationMean', 'numberOfAnalystOpinions']:
        if key in info:
            selected_info[key] = info[key]    
    selected_info['ISIN'] = isin
        
    return selected_info

    data = []
               
    # Loop over each ticker
    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            result = get_ticker_data(ticker)
            data.append(result)    
        except Exception:
            pass
               
    # Convert the list of dictionaries to a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    
    columns = ['marketCap', 'enterpriseValue']
    titles = ['Market Cap Distribution', 'Enterprise Value Distribution']
    
    for column, title in zip(columns, titles):
        # Create the histogram
        sns.displot(df[column], kde=True).set(title=title)
        
        filename = f'{column}_distribution.png'
        plt.savefig(filename, dpi=dpi)
        plt.close()
        
    presentation = Presentation()
    for column in columns:
        slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[6]  
        slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)    
        slide.shapes.add_picture(f'{column}_distribution.png', left, top)
    
    presentation.save('distributions.pptx')
```

As you can see the produced slide by Python is not 16:9, its the old Powerpoint format:

[image]

Comment: And `distribution.png` is good? Please don't shout "NO DUPLICATE". Your question looks like it's about figure resizing and resolution, so no wonder someone linked these topics. If they don't provide the answer, please remove all irrelevant parts from your code and leave the reproducible example, that is: trying to save 16:9 1080p figure and getting wrong result. Currently I can't even find what your `dpi` is so could as well just "close as typo".